# Cortana Integration in Unity

Tags: c#, xaml, unity-game-engine, windows-10, cortana

In order to create a little video game with voice interaction, I encounter few issues for Cortana integration in Unity. I have already made a little bot using *Luis AI*, *Cortana* and *Microsoft Bot Framework* which works fine on phone and laptop.

The main problem concerns the integration in Unity : some websites explain barely the way to follow and the best that I found uses code with download link that doesn’t work anymore (http://kevinashley.com/2015/06/24/unite-2015-integrating-cortana-with-unity-sample-project/#comment-498361).

If I understood well, some changes have to be made on the **App.xaml.cs** created.So here is my question : 
**Does anyone know a way to integrate Cortana in Unity ?**

Comment: Just build it as a `XAML` project or something like that. There's an option in the build settings for Unity to produce  complete visual studio project where you can modify `App.Xaml.cs` file and other `xaml` files

Comment: Have you tried to look into the Windows.Speech namespace? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.GrammarRecognizer.html

Comment: Thank you both, @m.rogalski this is precisely the modifications on the 'xaml' files that I don't know how to do . Everts, I will look your link, that might be helpful !